# How to make Go modules semantic import versioning v2+ work with vanity import path

Tags: git, go, import, go-modules

We are trying to migrate our Go code base to go modules and I can't figure out how to make it work with vanity import paths.

---

#### With `dep`

Until now our dependency management tool has been `dep`. We would place a `Gopkg.toml` file in our project root, and would define a dependency like:

```
[[constraint]]
  name = "mycompany.com/some-lib"
  version = "3.0.0"
```

As you can see, we use a so-called *vanity import path* for our own packages. In fact, our code is actually hosted on a private git server altogether. 
So along with this, we set up another server that renders HTML meta tags with repository information. E.g.:

```
<meta 
    name="go-import" 
    content="mycompany.com/some-lib git https://mygitserver.com/some-lib"
>
```

The mechanism is basically the one described in cmd/go docs, [Remote import paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths).

---

#### With go modules

So with go modules instead I have `export GO111MODULE=on` and a `go.mod` file that requires a dependency according to [semantic import versioning](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#semantic-import-versioning):

```
module foo

go 1.13

require (
    mycompany.com/some-lib/v3 v3.0.0
)
```

**Note** that the import path has the `v3` suffix as required by semantic import versioning. And the `some-lib` project also has its own `go.mod` file starting with: `module mycompany.com/some-lib/v3`.

Now my problem is that when `go get` or `go build` the dependency resolution fails with:
`go: mycompany.com/some-lib/v3@v3.0.0: unrecognized import path "mycompany.com/some-lib/v3" (parse https://mycompany.com/some-lib/v3?go-get=1: no go-import meta tags ())`

Of course this happens, because my remote import server handles `mycompany.com/some-lib` but not `mycompany.com/some-lib/v3`.

---

#### Question

- Isn't `go` command able to handle versioned imports automatically? I thought it would query for `mycompany.com/some-lib` and then fetch `v3` by itself.
- Am I supposed to handle every single `/vN` route in my remote import server?
- If so, what should I write in the `<meta>` tag? If not, what should I do?

**Bonus info**: I've seen some docs and articles recommending to basically duplicate the code under directories named after major versions, something like:

```
/               ---> contains v1.x.y code
|_ main.go
|_ interface.go
|_ go.mod
|_ /v2          ---> contains v2.x.y code
    |_ main.go
    |_ interface.go
    |_ go.mod
```

Or alternatively to maintain separate branches for each major version.
I don't want to do this. And I want to `require mycompany.com/some-lib/v3 v3.0.0` or `require mycompany.com/some-lib/v4 v4.1.0` based on each client project needs and fetch versions from the same place just as I did with `dep`.

**Bonus info 2:** curiously enough, ALL our project third-party dependencies either are not on go modules or are still on `v0` or `v1` versions or just hosted on github, so I can't find applicable examples.

Any insight is extremely appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I supposed to handle every single `/vN` route in my remote import server?

Yes. (You are already supposed to handle every path that may correspond to a package within the repository: see https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths.)

> If so, what should I write in the `<meta>` tag?

Exactly the same thing that you are writing today should work: the same paths, with no `/vN` suffix needed unless you want to route different versions to different repositories.